# bash dynamic variable

Tags: bash

I would like to use dynamic variable in function.
Can you please let me know how can I do it?
Basically

```
function () {

variable_$*=$SECONDS

}

function test

echo $variable_test
```

Which needs to show time to spend on the script for example 1

Comment: Don't get it .. but think you should rather save the systime on top of the function and than compare it to the systime before leaving the function..

Comment: My concern is not about the system time. It was only an example, I would like to learn how to use dynamic variable like variable_$*=$another_variable

Comment: Not clear. You want the function to create a variable with name that you give to function as argument ?   Give more examples or explain cases where this would be necessary.

Comment: function () {

variable_$*=$another_variable

}

function test

echo $variable_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (mis)use `export` (for exported variables) or `printf` (for others):

```
foo () {
    printf -v "variable_$1" "%s" "$SECONDS"
}
```

Then:

```
$ foo bar
$ echo $variable_bar
237
```

With export:

```
foo () {
    export "variable_$1=$SECONDS"
}
```

Comment: Another question how to use variable_$1 in if and echo.
example:
if I need to print it echo what is the correct form
echo $variable_$1 doesn't work
also I would like to use it in if check how should I use variable_$1 in if?
Thanks

Comment: Another question how to use variable_$1 in if and echo.
example:
if I need to print it echo what is the correct form
echo $variable_$1 doesn't work
also I would like to use it in if check how should I use variable_$1 in if?
Thanks